# 3-dimentional vector space over the field $\,F_3=\Bbb Z/3 \Bbb Z$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional vector space over the field $\,F_3=\Bbb Z/3 \Bbb Z$ of $3$ element.Then what is the number of distinct 2-dimentional subspace of $V$ ?

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ to typeset mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) How many linearly independent sets with two vectors are there?

2) The span of many of the above yield the same subspaces?

You may want *better* to check how many one - dimensional subspaces are there (why?)